# Bash: How to grab columns with "delimiter" within the column from CSV file?

Tags: bash, awk, text-parsing

I have a few CSV files I have downloaded from an online database. I am trying to cut them down so that I can insert the portions of the data that I need into my SQL database.

The CSV file has comma-separated fields and looks like this:

```
1,Peptidoglycan synthetase ftsI,ftsI,1574687,L42023,P45059,FTSI_HAEIN,"",,,,
3,Histidine decarboxylase,HDC,32109,X54297,P19113,DCHS_HUMAN,,HDC,HDC,HGNC:4855,00817
5,"Glutaminase liver isoform, mitochondrial",GLS2,6650606,AF110330,Q9UI32,GLSL_HUMAN,,GLS2,GLS2,HGNC:29570,05901
6,Coagulation factor XIII A chain,F13A1,182309,M22001,P00488,F13A_HUMAN,1FIE,F13A1,F13A1,HGNC:3531,00604
7,"Nitric oxide synthase, inducible",NOS2,292242,L09210,P35228,NOS2_HUMAN,2NSI,NOS2A,NOS2A,HGNC:7873,01225
```

And here is the problem. Look at the 3rd and the 5th lines. The 2nd column of those two lines have commas in them! I usually use awk for something like this, and because of that comma being there $2 gets messed up.

So for example:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' myfile.csv ## Obviously I will be printing a lot more stuff
```

If that was done to that portion as shown above, the 3rd and 5th line will be screwed up because 2nd column of those two lines have a comma in them enclosed by quotation marks.

What could I do to get around this?

EDIT: I'd like to still stick to doing this in shell if possible.

Comment: You need a tool trained to handle CSV format when the delimiter appears in the fields (as the commas appear in some fields).  Consider Perl and [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV), or perhaps [`csvfix`](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).  There are probably similar modules for Python or Ruby if they're to your taste.  But generally, the grey hairs you'll get from struggling to make tools like `awk` 'work' with CSV aren't worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a CSV parser like [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) (in a one-liner (so still in shell) if you want), it will do all the magic for you.

If instead you prefer [python](/questions/tagged/python), see the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

An example in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) + [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
$ python<<EOF
import csv

f = open("test.csv", 'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
finally:
    f.close()
EOF
```

Comment: I don't use Perl at all (use Python and shell). Wouldn't I need to know some Perl to use that?

Comment: That's the same link, by the way. http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html I saw that, but I'd prefer stick in shell if I can... do you think Text::CSV would be better for that?